# Create Files,Debug Step By Step,Crash--EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

- I want to create test.txt file, sample codes.
- I run this app, well done.
- But when I debug app step by step, it crash, report
  (EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_l386_GPFLT)),method:
  FileManager.default.createFile()

---

SWIFT CODES:

---

```
import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
        @IBAction func CreateFileButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            createFiles()
        }
        
        private func createFiles() {
            let manager = FileManager.default
            let urlForDocument = manager.urls( for: .documentDirectory,
                                               in:.userDomainMask)
            let url = urlForDocument[0]
            createFile(name:"test.txt", fileBaseUrl: url)
        }
        func createFile(name:String, fileBaseUrl:URL){
            let manager = FileManager.default
            
            let file = fileBaseUrl.appendingPathComponent(name)
            print("f: \(file)")
            let exist = manager.fileExists(atPath: file.path)
            if !exist {
                let data = Data(base64Encoded:"aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=" ,options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                let createSuccess = manager.createFile(atPath: file.path,contents:data,attributes:nil)
                print("f: \(createSuccess)")
            }
        }
    }
```

---

[image]

^ Crash step method:FileManager.default.createFile()
[image]

^Crash report
[image]

^Just run app, do not debug, it well done

Comment: I think the value of data is nil. Debug and check the value of data.

Comment: I just run app, with out debug step by step, it well done, no crash, y?@swapnilpatel